# Simple regex to extract img src attribute's value

Tags: regex

I try to make a simple regex with Rubular

I want to capture all the url (src) with img id "zoom-product-image" where img_b.jpg match.

I've tried with this regex

**/ id="zoom-product-image" src="(.*?)"**

This will leave me with 3 matches.

/product-images/545442_img_a.jpg

/product-images/5453112_img_b.jpg

/product-images/595512_img_c.jpg

But i need only match witch containing img_b.jpg so I've tried to use this regex:

**/ id="zoom-product-image" src="(.*?_img_b.jpg)"**

But this does not work

HTML test string:

```
<li class=""><img id="zoom-product-image" src="/product-images/545442_img_a.jpg" alt="Red img"> </li><li><img id="zoom-product-image" src="/product-images/5453112_img_b.jpg" alt="Green img"></li><li><img id="zoom-product-image" src="/product-images/595512_img_c.jpg" alt="Blue img"></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to meet your requirements:

```
 id="zoom-product-image" src="([^_]*_img_b\.jpg)
```

Breaking it down:

- id="zoom-product-image" src="   : match everything beginning with
  this string
- (            : begin capture
- [^_]*        : match 0 or more characters that are NOT _
- _img_b.jpg   : match this string
- )            : end capture

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but it works

`/id="zoom-product-image" src="([^"]*_img_b\.jpg)"/g`

`[^"]*` means - anything but `"` 0 or more times

Comment: To match literal `.` needs to be escaped `\.` from it's [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)